# Export interactive google map as a static image

Tags: google-maps, jupyter

I am creating certain heatmaps using [gmaps](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps) which is a jupyter extension. The output of this library are interactive google maps like one [here](https://www.jefftk.com/apartment_prices/index#2017-03-19&2).

I want the final output to be a png image which *should* be obtainable via google static maps but I don't know how do I convert a map with an extra layer of heatmap to a static map programatically.

Is it possible to convert a map like [this](https://www.jefftk.com/apartment_prices/index#2017-03-19&2) to a static image.

Thanks

Comment: +1 - Would love to know how to take the gmap in juypter and just convert to a png to be displayed within the same juypter notebook so once I download the notebook as html, the image will be displayed when viewing the notebook offline.

Comment: There's no way to do it directly, as it's not functionality supported by Google Static Maps. The plugin (and example) you show adds the heatmap as a single image to the overlay layer, so you should be able to get access to that image and the map image (using google static maps api). You could then overlay the heatmap image over the static map image. The problem will be getting them to line up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a heatmap, you can't solely relies on the static map api, you will either grab the tiles from using a Google Maps API for JavaScript and lay them out in your canvas or container or a backend service or use some other heatmap libraries to output the layer in the same projection that you use for Google Maps API (defaults to Web Mercator) as a PNG and overlay on top your static map image.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat late to the party, but I'm the author of [gmaps](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps), the jupyter widget mentioned in the question.

You can now export PNGs from `gmaps`:

```
$ pip install -U gmaps
$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps
```

You can then create a map with an *export* button:

```python
import gmaps
gmaps.__version__ # => 0.4.2.rc3

gmaps.configure(api_key="...")

fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer([(50.0, 5.0), (52.0, 6.0)]))
fig
```

[image]

If you click the download button, it will export the map to a PNG.

For limitations, read the [documentation](http://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gmaps.html#exporting-maps)

---

For reference, the static API is not well suited for maps with significant amounts of data overlaid (as would be typical for heatmaps), since there is an upper limit to the amount of data that the API accepts. Currently this is limited to 8192 bytes.

Comment: Thanks this is useful.  Is there a way to export as a div and embed the map into a non jupyter html document?

Comment: Thanks -- not yet, but that's coming soon on the roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for the update @PascalBugnion. I'll try out the PR.

Comment: This is now available in a prerelease from pypi, so you don't have to build from source. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @PascalBugnion Is it possible to use it also in Spyder IDE?

Comment: Is it possible to save the figure with a line of code to disk as PNG?